# Check that one can find a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check that for any $\delta >0$ one can find a sequence $(\epsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of strictly positive reals such that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon_n <\delta$$

Any hint?

Comment: Let $\epsilon_n = \frac{\delta}{2^{n+2}}$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Consider the decimal expansion of $\delta$, and if $\delta$ has a finite decimal expansion, replace, e.g. $1.23$ by $1.2299\ldots$

Comment: Hmmm... yeah, what more?

Comment: @MZ97 e.g. if $\delta = \pi$, consider $2 + 0.9 + 0.99 + 0.999 + \ldots = 3 < \pi$ and rescale for any other $\delta$ of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon_n=\frac \delta{3^{n+1}}$ for example

Comment: yeah, this will give us $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon_n <\delta$$. But is there any other way to show it more formaly?

Comment: It explicitly makes the sum $\frac \delta 2$  What do you mean, more formally?  I gave a value for each $\epsilon_n$

Comment: It'a real analysis, I need to check that it works for every delta

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{3{n+1}}=\frac 12$ (note I increased the exponent by $1$ because the sum starts at $n=0$), so it is just the distributive principle.  This is allowed because the series is absolutely convergent.